# What is missing that is causing maps to crash after first load?

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
    package com.example.myapplication;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission;


public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {


    private LocationManager locationManager;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
//   double myLong;
//   double myLat;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            getLocation();

        }

        mMapView = mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }

    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());

        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(39.918837, -82.831853)).title("Bowzers").snippet("Where Our Dogs Are NOT JUST A DOG"));
        CameraPosition Bowzers = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(39.918837, -82.831853)).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(Bowzers));


    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,@NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
        if(requestCode == 1|| grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code that I am using to load maps and place one marker on it.  It works on the first load but after that it just keeps crashing.  A solution and an explanation would be greatful.  Thank You to all in advanced. Eventually I would like to add a second marker of where I am at based on GPS coordinates.  Before I can do that I need to get the map working with one marker that will be the same all the time.

Comment: Alright, so I removed a lot of code and now it works no matter how many times you leave the maps screen to another and back.  Now the issue is how do I get what is posted to work to get current location and add a marker to the map (initial LONG and LAT only), and then how to get it to put a moving blue dot on it that moves when device moves?  thank you everyone.

Comment: then take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

Comment: Okay so I still not sure what is what.  I can use samples with no problem.  The second I try to move it over to my project it all goes south with 50 million red lines.  I have to change this to getActivity(), then I get something about abstract.  I am creating an app that is using fragments.  So all of the traditional stuff is not working and I have tried following 50+ tutorials and the only thing I can get is a map with a marker.  I want a map with a marker with the static location.  Will be the same all the time.  And then a marker that updates with GPS location of current user.  Thank you.

Comment: Using maps in fragments is a little different. Can you attach your log?

Comment: I have never written code with fragments before and it is very very trying.  I am not sure but to use the anser your question button to paste my cleaned up code and then we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;




public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    private LocationManager locationManager;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



        mMapView = mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if (mMapView != null) {
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());

        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(39.918837, -82.831853)).title("Bowzers").snippet("Where Our Dogs Are NOT JUST A DOG"));
        CameraPosition Bowzers = CameraPosition.builder().target(new LatLng(39.918837, -82.831853)).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(Bowzers));


    }




}
```

So the above code is what is currently working for stage 1 of my project.  It displays a map and puts a marker on the one and only desitination that will be marked.  Now this is within a fragment.  The next bit of code if I use it in a stand alone project works just great, but not sure how to move it over into a fragment. My overall goal though is to show where one is on the map and have it update as they are moving while keeping a pin for the one and only destination on the map.  I don't need directons or polylines, just a marker that updates as the user device moves.

### Below is code that works as a stand alone just to get GPS location.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CurrentLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    public static String tvLongi;
    public static String tvLati;
    TextView tvLatitude;
    TextView tvLongitude;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CheckPermission();
    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getLocation();
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    public void getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void CheckPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
        tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);
        // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
        tvLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

        tvLongi = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        tvLati = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());

        // Setting Current Longitude
        tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + tvLongi);
        // Setting Current Latitude
        tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + tvLati);
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(CurrentLocationActivity.this, "Please Enable GPS and Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider!" + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciative.  Thank You